# dynammic way to use the same code for employeeID and employeeName

Tags: node.js

I have this project in order to return "the employee's screenshots", and I set up the api to return the screenshots:

```
     http://localhost:3000/employee/screenshot/14ll0a54kb9kkvh8?page=5
```

employeeId="14ll0a54kb9kkvh8".............................................,
and with this api i pass the employee Id and the postman return screenshots for this employee , and the code is at the bottom, but in any case I want to pass the "employee’s name" not the "employee's Id" to the api, so how can I add this thing to the code, "in a dynamic way", meaning without returning to write all this same code ?
I need to have two api with the same  code ,the first api with id and the second with name:

```
   http://localhost:3000/employee/screenshot/14ll0a54kb9kkvh8?page=5
   http://localhost:3000/employee/screenshot/George?page=5
```

screenshotServices.js:

```
     async getAll(employeeId, pageNumber, pageSize) {
     // Grab images from db according to pagination data and uid
     const dbImages = await ScreenshotModel
        .findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                employeeId: employeeId
            },
            limit: pageSize,
            offset: (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize
        })
        .then(screenshots => {
            // console.log(dbRes);
            const imagesData = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < screenshots.rows.length; i++) {
                imagesData.push(screenshots.rows[i]['dataValues']);
            }
            return imagesData;
        })
        .catch(dbError => {
            console.log(dbError);
            return null;
        });

       if (dbImages === null) return dbImages;


       // Database returns images paths
       // Now we need to get the actual images from files

       // getting images paths from db response
       const imagePaths = [];
       for (let i = 0; i < dbImages.length; i++) {
        imagePaths.push(dbImages[i]['imagePath']);
       }
       const directoryPath = rootDirectory + `/images/screenshots/${employeeId}`;
       // Grabbing images from files
        return await ScreenshotModel
        .findAllInDirectoryWithSpecifiedImagePaths(directoryPath, imagePaths)
        .then(readFromDirectoryResponse => {
            return readFromDirectoryResponse;
        })
        .catch(readFromDirectoryError => {
            console.log(readFromDirectoryError);
            return null;
        });
        }
        module.exports = ScreenshotService;
```

screenshotController.js:

```
   const _getAll = async (req, res) => {
       // Grabbing data
       const employeeId = req.params['id'];
       // Pagination data
       const pageNumber = +req.query['page'];
        const pageSize = 3;
       // console.log(uid);
       // console.log(pageNumber);
       const screenshots = await ScreenshotService.Instance.getAll(employeeId, pageNumber, 
       pageSize);
       if(screenshots === null)
       return res.status(500).json({message: 'failed', screenshots: screenshots});
       return res.status(200).json({message: 'succeeded', screenshots: screenshots});
       };
     module.exports = {
           getAll: _getAll
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution should be separate the entry point (the endpoint) and receive different param values, then each endpoint goes to a common function.

other solution is to write a regex then you can identify if the incoming value is an id or a name.

EDIT:

screenshotController.js:

```
const criteriaRegex  = new RegExp('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$'); // define this in a global place

const _getAll = async (req, res) => {
        const filter = {};
       // Grabbing data
       const critieria = req.params['id'];
        if (criteriaRegex.test(critieria)){ // if true is because the ID is alphanumeric, thus, we assume this is an ID
            filter = {employeeId: critieria}
        } else {
            filter = {employeeName: critieria}
        }
       // Pagination data
       const pageNumber = +req.query['page'];
        const pageSize = 3;
       // console.log(uid);
       // console.log(pageNumber);
       const screenshots = await ScreenshotService.Instance.getAll(filter, pageNumber, 
       pageSize);
       if(screenshots === null)
       return res.status(500).json({message: 'failed', screenshots: screenshots});
       return res.status(200).json({message: 'succeeded', screenshots: screenshots});
       };
     module.exports = {
           getAll: _getAll
      };
```

screenshotServices.js:

```
async getAll(filter, pageNumber, pageSize) {
     // Grab images from db according to pagination data and uid
     const dbImages = await ScreenshotModel
        .findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                ...filter
            },
            limit: pageSize,
            offset: (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize
        })
        .then(screenshots => {
            // console.log(dbRes);
            const imagesData = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < screenshots.rows.length; i++) {
                imagesData.push(screenshots.rows[i]['dataValues']);
            }
            return imagesData;
        })
        .catch(dbError => {
            console.log(dbError);
            return null;
        });

       if (dbImages === null) return dbImages;


       // Database returns images paths
       // Now we need to get the actual images from files

       // getting images paths from db response
       const imagePaths = [];
       for (let i = 0; i < dbImages.length; i++) {
        imagePaths.push(dbImages[i]['imagePath']);
       }
       const directoryPath = rootDirectory + `/images/screenshots/${employeeId}`;
       // Grabbing images from files
        return await ScreenshotModel
        .findAllInDirectoryWithSpecifiedImagePaths(directoryPath, imagePaths)
        .then(readFromDirectoryResponse => {
            return readFromDirectoryResponse;
        })
        .catch(readFromDirectoryError => {
            console.log(readFromDirectoryError);
            return null;
        });
        }
        module.exports = ScreenshotService;
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can i doing what you say in this Code ? , I means I know this way but I don't know how can i make it in the code above

Comment: @NourGeorge I just added an example.